# Index.html not rendering component when served through Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm at the end of following this tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/

and I have changed my App.js to the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>lmfao</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now unfortunately, while visiting localhost:5000 after running "***npm run dev***", although the page title says 'React App' and the page source is index.html, the App component is not rendered and there are not errors anywhere.

Here's a picture of visiting localhost:5000 which gives index.html
[image: blank index.html]

Now thw funny thing is, if I visit the React server on localhost:3000, the component does render.

What am I missing? 
Many Thanks

P.S Here's Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Static file declaration
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

// production mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
  //  app.get('*', (req, res) => {    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname = 'client/build/index.html'));  })
}

// build mode
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/public/index.html"));
});

// start server
app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`server listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Here are the dependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  }
```

**EDIT**: As requested, here's a github link for the project:
https://github.com/Dobermensch/ExpressTest.git
You'll have to do ***npm install*** for both the *ExpressTest* folder and the *client* sub-folder

Comment: The first thing I would do is open the network tab in devtools (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) for each page then refresh them. Determine if the same content is getting served. Then you'll have a better idea where to go from there.

Comment: can you please push code on github and share the link? That will help in debugging.

Comment: Done, please have a look.

Comment: It seems I had to add the client folder as a submodule in git. It is done now. Let me know if things work...

Comment: Since the express server is running from the build folder, have you run `npm run build` after making this change?

Comment: Actually following the tutorial, I've been running 'npm run dev'. dev is defined in package.json in ExpressTest folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting a blank page is that script bundle(s) cannot be downloaded.

In the browser right-click on the blank page and choose "View Page Source" or similar menu. You will see the content of the .html file including `<script>` tag(s) which point to `/some-path/some-name.js` file(s). Either all or some of those files cannot be downloaded. To confirm this is the case just download the bundle manually by pointing the browser to `localhost:5000/some-path/some-name.js`. If the script bundle cannot be downloaded, add a route to Express.

Comment: There aren't any script tags in my index.html

Comment: Then it is the problem which explains the blank page. The freecodecamp [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/) you referred to uses Create React App (CRA). CRA creates `index.html` with `<script src="/static/js/<some-name>chunk.js"></script>` at the bottom of the file. These `<name>.chunk.js` files are React script bundles. What you see on the page is the result of the execution of the code from the bundle(s). No bundles = blank page.

Comment: if CRA creates index.html with those bundles automatically then why isn't it in my index.html? and how do I get it there?

Comment: interesting... you led me to the right answer I had to go to the client folder, then run `npm run build` and then I just ran the server (npm run dev) in the ExpressTest folder again and it worked on localhost:5000

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)